# Insert Variable Into SQL Query Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, variables

I have a SQL query that looks like this;

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT ID, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "month_of_sale, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "client_last_name, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "client_first_name, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "deal_number, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "stock_number, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "delivery_date, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "finance_manager, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "finance_income, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "record_entered " & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "FROM(dodge_records)" & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "WHERE month_of_sale = @month_of_sale AND client_last_name = @client_last_name" & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "ORDER BY client_last_name"
```

I am trying to insert a variable into the SQL query but I don't see it happening when I debug the website. Here is the rest of the code so that it makes more sense.

```
Case "Last Name"
                    Try
                        Dim query As String = "SELECT ID, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "month_of_sale, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "client_last_name, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "client_first_name, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "deal_number, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "stock_number, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "delivery_date, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "finance_manager, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "finance_income, " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "record_entered " & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "FROM(dodge_records)" & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "WHERE month_of_sale = @month_of_sale" & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "WHERE client_last_name = @client_last_name" & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "ORDER BY client_last_name"

                        Using Connection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
                            Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, Connection)
                                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month_of_sale", CurrentMonth)
                                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_last_name", ValueBoxText)
                                Dim DS As New DataSet
                                da.Fill(DS)
                                DodgeSearchGridView.DataSource = DS
                                DodgeSearchGridView.DataBind()
                                Connection.Close()
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try
```

CurrentMonth & ValueBoxText are strings that I need inserted into the SQL query. Right now this isn't working how I want it to. I don't get an error message or anything, the query doesn't return anything and I have double checked the database to make sure there is data in it that would be returned by this query. Can anyone help me error check the code so I can find out how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: where are you using this parameter `@client_last_name` in your sql?

Comment: @rs. I updated the code. I'm not sure why it was left out.

Comment: Your sql statement is still not valid sql, i think you need `" AND client_last_name = @client_last_name"`

Comment: @rs. Ok I have made those changes. I still don't see the GridView populating with the data. I have another query that runs without inserting variables and it looks identical to this and it populates its own GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is incorrect.  You have used WHERE twice.  The second condition should use AND ie 
AND client_last_name

Comment: I have edited my code. I still don't see the GridView populating with the data. I have another query that runs without inserting variables and it looks identical to this and it populates its own GridView.

Comment: change your exception handling.  You are not displaying exceptions.  Remove the Try Catch or add code to output the exception after the Catch.  IE Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: " & ex.Message)

Comment: I made those changes and nothing was written to the console window. That means the query went through ok?

Comment: I corrected the typo which is why the grid wasn't populating. Thanks!

Comment: So you have a binding issue or a SQL issue.  After the line  da.Fill(DS) you want to check if there are any records in the data set.  Add a watch and look at DS.Tables.Count if this value is 1 look at DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count.  If this value is greater than 1 you have a binding issue.  If it is zero then there is still and SQL issue.  If it is a SQL issue there is likely something up with the varibles CurrentMonth or ValueBoxText.  You should edit your code to show how the values for those varibles are assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Step through the code in the VS debugger and paste the query generated from the command into SQL Server Management studio and try it there.